# use git cherry-pick now but merge changes later

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches and want to cherry-pick a change from one and move it to the other. At a later date, when I merge the two repositories what effect will the cherry-pick have since the commit IDs will be different but the content will be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the changed region is not affected in a later commit, the merge will ignore the regions changed in the cherry-pick, since they will be identical in each branch.  If you later change one of the regions in one branch but not the other, you may have to resolve a conflict as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This approach expect that the other branch (`fix-branch`) hasn't been pushed to origin (=> it can be rebased). To avoid that, we can **rebase** instead of merge:

```
git rebase master fix-branch
```

Now we are in fix-branch, master is bellow. Continue to switch back to master and merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge fix-branch
```

[Source](https://davitenio.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/git-merge-after-git-cherry-pick-avoiding-duplicate-commits/)